# Need a secure way of granting access to xp_cmdshell

Tags: security, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Imagine the following scenario: I need to execute a stored procedure which, amongst other things, needs to EXECUTE xp_cmdshell to run a command-line script which executes a bulk insert (bcp) command to put data into another database.

I have three Windows user accounts on the server: MyAdmin, MyProxy and MyUser.

MyAdmin is db_owner of the database and has bulkadmin server role.
MyProxy is the account associated with `xp_cmdshell` via `sp_xpcmdshell_proxy_account`.
MyUser has EXECUTE permission on the stored procedure and nothing else.

If I login as SERVER\MyUser and execute the stored procedure, it fails with error "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_cmdshell', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

So I thought the answer was to grant EXECUTE on `xp_cmdshell` to MyProxy, but this didn't work either. I then granted EXECUTE on `xp_cmdshell` to MyAdmin and changed the definition of the stored procedure to WITH EXECUTE AS 'MyAdmin' and although `xp_cmdshell` is executed OK, the bulk insert fails.

What must I do to make this scenario work?

Update: was asked on StackOverflow.com (1440332), but got no answers - hoping for better result here

Comment: Is this an on-demand type of operation or scheduled?

Comment: what is the error you get when the bcp fails?

Comment: Sam: ultimately, it will be run as a scheduled task via SQLAgent/SSIS.
SQLRockstar: error msg is "you need bulk insert permissions to execute bulk copy operations" or something to that effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to remember a BCP step in SSIS.  Could you create a SSIS package and run that?  You can run SSIS packages from .net.

Comment: Interestingly, I do have a potential future requirement to create an SSIS package which amongst other things, will execute this procedure, so this is a definite possibility - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would have made this a comment instead of an 'answer' had I permissions to do so, but, why not use the BULK INSERT T-SQL command instead of xp_cmdshell to bcp?

Comment: The stored procedure can execute any command-line executable file, which is done via xp_cmdshell. Executing bcp commands is one of many tasks the procedure can perform.